# How to use SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, token, secure-random

I'm really new to this and need to create an url-safe token of between 2 and 20 characters and only alphanumeric chars (letters and numbers) are allowed. I use this token for processing by a payment provider.

I have the method below, but I got an error that the token was invalid. How can I rewrite the method so that it's still url-safe but does not exceed 20 characters and only uses alphanumeric chars?

```
token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64) `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` will return “-” and “_” which are characters you've said you don't want.

You can use `SecureRandom.hex(n)` to get `2*n` chars containing a-z and 0-9. It's still URL safe. Your final code will be:

```
token = SecureRandom.hex # without `n` token will be 16 characters long.
```

Comment: I tried it but got the same error. Then I just tried `SecureRandom.hex` in the console and it turned out this produces 32 characters. So I tried `SecureRandom.hex(20)` in the console, and this produced 40 characters. With `SecureRandom.hex(10)` it produces 20 characters and it works. Not sure what explains the behavior though.

Comment: As per documentation it's 2*n characters long. You can see it here http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-hex

Comment: Just a note. Hexadecimal isn't alphanumerical. `SecureRandom.hex(n)` will generate the first, so only **0-9** and **a-f** will be present in the generated string.